# Mac OS X x11vnc Reverse connection display geometry w:0 h:0 and client shows black screen

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, vnc, opengl, x11vnc

I’m trying to stablish reverse connection between my Mac and a VNC viewer but it seems OpenGL can’t calculate my display geometry, width and height are zero sized and the viewer just gets a black screen.

I’m able to use the viewer to remote control the Mac if I do a normal connection, the problem just occurs when I try reverse connection.

My OS details:
macOS Big Sur 11.5.2

MacBook Pro 13 2020
Apple M1
8 gb

I’ve tried several different options but none of them seems to do the job.

Important: the viewer listener is configured correctly, I can start a reverse connection using the same listener from Linux and Windows.
There is a repeater configured on the listener side where the port is 5500 and connection ID is 1234.

The most simple version of the command I use to start the remote connection is:
x11vnc -display :0 -connect repeater=ID:1234+192.168.15.149:5500

Output I get is below, the last block of lines keeps looping and showing w: 0 , h: 0 and the display is always black on listener side!
Could you help me on what can I do to get it working ?
Thank you very much !!

Output :

lvus@MacBook-Pro-de-Daniel ~ % x11vnc -display :0 -connect repeater=ID:1234+192.168.15.149:5500
###############################################################

```
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
#@ @#
#@ ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** @#
#@ @#
#@ YOU ARE RUNNING X11VNC WITHOUT A PASSWORD!! @#
#@ @#
#@ This means anyone with network access to this computer @#
#@ may be able to view and control your desktop. @#
#@ @#
#@ >>> If you did not mean to do this Press CTRL-C now!! <<< @#
#@ @#
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
#@ @#
#@ You can create an x11vnc password file by running: @#
#@ @#
#@ x11vnc -storepasswd password /path/to/passfile @#
#@ or x11vnc -storepasswd /path/to/passfile @#
#@ or x11vnc -storepasswd @#
#@ @#
#@ (the last one will use ~/.vnc/passwd) @#
#@ @#
#@ and then starting x11vnc via: @#
#@ @#
#@ x11vnc -rfbauth /path/to/passfile @#
#@ @#
#@ an existing ~/.vnc/passwd file from another VNC @#
#@ application will work fine too. @#
#@ @#
#@ You can also use the -passwdfile or -passwd options. @#
#@ (note -passwd is unsafe if local users are not trusted) @#
#@ @#
#@ Make sure any -rfbauth and -passwdfile password files @#
#@ cannot be read by untrusted users. @#
#@ @#
#@ Use x11vnc -usepw to automatically use your @#
#@ ~/.vnc/passwd or ~/.vnc/passwdfile password files. @#
#@ (and prompt you to create ~/.vnc/passwd if neither @#
#@ file exists.) Under -usepw, x11vnc will exit if it @#
#@ cannot find a password to use. @#
#@ @#
#@ @#
#@ Even with a password, the subsequent VNC traffic is @#
#@ sent in the clear. Consider tunnelling via ssh(1): @#
#@ @#
#@ http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/#tunnelling @#
#@ @#
#@ Or using the x11vnc SSL options: -ssl and -stunnel @#
#@ @#
#@ Please Read the documention for more info about @#
#@ passwords, security, and encryption. @#
#@ @#
#@ http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-passwd @#
#@ @#
#@ To disable this warning use the -nopw option, or put @#
#@ 'nopw' on a line in your ~/.x11vncrc file. @#
#@ @#
#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#
###############################################################
02/09/2021 10:31:38 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05 pid: 45991
02/09/2021 10:31:38 This x11vnc was built without X11 support (-rawfb only).
02/09/2021 10:31:38 Continuing without X display in -rawfb mode.
02/09/2021 10:31:38 macosxCG_init: initializing display.
02/09/2021 10:31:39 macosx_opengl_init: Using OpenGL for screen capture.
02/09/2021 10:31:39 console_guess: file is /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:39 console_guess returned: map:macosx:/dev/null@0x0x32:ff0000/ff00/ff
02/09/2021 10:31:39 raw fb is non-regular file: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:39 CGDisplayBaseAddress disabled by OpenGL.
02/09/2021 10:31:39 rawfb: macosx fb: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:39 w: 0 h: 0 b: 32 addr: 0x0 sz: 0
02/09/2021 10:31:39 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/0
02/09/2021 10:31:39
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Raw fb at addr 0x0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
02/09/2021 10:31:39
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Autoprobing TCP port
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5901
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Autoprobing TCP6 port
02/09/2021 10:31:39 rfbListenOnTCP6Port: error in bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5901
02/09/2021 10:31:39 listen6: bind: Address already in use
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Manually set num_buttons to: 5
02/09/2021 10:31:39 macosx_console: copied screen in 0.000 sec 0.0 MB/sec
02/09/2021 10:31:39 screen setup finished.
02/09/2021 10:31:39
02/09/2021 10:31:39 WARNING: You are running x11vnc WITHOUT a password. See
02/09/2021 10:31:39 WARNING: the warning message printed above for more info.
02/09/2021 10:31:39

The VNC desktop is: MacBook-Pro-de-Daniel.local:1
PORT=5901
02/09/2021 10:31:39 -connect prestring: 'ID:1234'
02/09/2021 10:31:39 connect_tcp: trying: 192.168.15.149 5500
02/09/2021 10:31:39 0 other clients
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Normal socket connection
02/09/2021 10:31:39 macosxCG_refresh_callback: register
02/09/2021 10:31:39 incr accepted_client=1 for 192.168.15.149:5500 sock=11
02/09/2021 10:31:39 reverse_connect: 192.168.15.149:5500/192.168.15.149 OK
02/09/2021 10:31:39 reverse_connect: turning on auth for 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 client progressed=0 in 15/10 0.000508 s
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Client Protocol Version 3.8
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
02/09/2021 10:31:39 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 1
02/09/2021 10:31:39 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: returning securityResult for client rfb version >= 3.8
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:39 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:39 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:39 no translation needed
02/09/2021 10:31:39 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type ultraZip
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Using compression level 3 for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling cursor position updates for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling KeyboardLedState protocol extension for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling SupportedMessages protocol extension for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling SupportedEncodings protocol extension for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Enabling ServerIdentity protocol extension for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:39 Using ZRLE encoding for client 192.168.15.149
02/09/2021 10:31:40 macosxCG_refresh_callback: unregister
02/09/2021 10:31:40 deleted 1 tile_row polling images.
02/09/2021 10:31:40 macosxCG_init: initializing display.
02/09/2021 10:31:40 macosx_opengl_init: Using OpenGL for screen capture.
02/09/2021 10:31:40 console_guess: file is /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:40 console_guess returned: map:macosx:/dev/null@0x0x32:ff0000/ff00/ff
02/09/2021 10:31:40 raw fb is non-regular file: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:40 CGDisplayBaseAddress disabled by OpenGL.
02/09/2021 10:31:40 rawfb: macosx fb: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:40 w: 0 h: 0 b: 32 addr: 0x0 sz: 0
02/09/2021 10:31:40 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/0
02/09/2021 10:31:40 rfbNewFramebuffer(0x2af31eb0, 0x0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 4)
02/09/2021 10:31:40 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:40 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:40 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:40
02/09/2021 10:31:40 Raw fb at addr 0x0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
02/09/2021 10:31:40
02/09/2021 10:31:40 calling setTranslateFunction()...
02/09/2021 10:31:40 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:40 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:40 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:40 no translation needed
02/09/2021 10:31:40 done.
02/09/2021 10:31:40 Sending rfbEncodingNewFBSize for resize to (0x0)
02/09/2021 10:31:40 client_set_net: 192.168.15.149 0.0115
02/09/2021 10:31:40 macosxCG_refresh_callback: register
02/09/2021 10:31:41 macosxCG_refresh_callback: unregister
02/09/2021 10:31:41 deleted 1 tile_row polling images.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 macosxCG_init: initializing display.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 macosx_opengl_init: Using OpenGL for screen capture.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 console_guess: file is /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:41 console_guess returned: map:macosx:/dev/null@0x0x32:ff0000/ff00/ff
02/09/2021 10:31:41 raw fb is non-regular file: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:41 CGDisplayBaseAddress disabled by OpenGL.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 rawfb: macosx fb: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:41 w: 0 h: 0 b: 32 addr: 0x0 sz: 0
02/09/2021 10:31:41 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/0
02/09/2021 10:31:41 rfbNewFramebuffer(0x2af31eb0, 0x0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 4)
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:41 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:41 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:41
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Raw fb at addr 0x0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
02/09/2021 10:31:41
02/09/2021 10:31:41 calling setTranslateFunction()...
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:41 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:41 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:41 no translation needed
02/09/2021 10:31:41 done.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Sending rfbEncodingNewFBSize for resize to (0x0)
02/09/2021 10:31:41 macosxCG_refresh_callback: register
02/09/2021 10:31:41 macosxCG_refresh_callback: unregister
02/09/2021 10:31:41 deleted 1 tile_row polling images.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 macosxCG_init: initializing display.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 macosx_opengl_init: Using OpenGL for screen capture.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 console_guess: file is /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:41 console_guess returned: map:macosx:/dev/null@0x0x32:ff0000/ff00/ff
02/09/2021 10:31:41 raw fb is non-regular file: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:41 CGDisplayBaseAddress disabled by OpenGL.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 rawfb: macosx fb: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:41 w: 0 h: 0 b: 32 addr: 0x0 sz: 0
02/09/2021 10:31:41 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/0
02/09/2021 10:31:41 rfbNewFramebuffer(0x2af31eb0, 0x0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 4)
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:41 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:41 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:41
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Raw fb at addr 0x0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
02/09/2021 10:31:41
02/09/2021 10:31:41 calling setTranslateFunction()...
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:41 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:41 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:41 no translation needed
02/09/2021 10:31:41 done.
02/09/2021 10:31:41 Sending rfbEncodingNewFBSize for resize to (0x0)
02/09/2021 10:31:42 macosxCG_refresh_callback: register
02/09/2021 10:31:43 macosxCG_refresh_callback: unregister
02/09/2021 10:31:43 deleted 1 tile_row polling images.
02/09/2021 10:31:43 macosxCG_init: initializing display.
02/09/2021 10:31:43 macosx_opengl_init: Using OpenGL for screen capture.
02/09/2021 10:31:43 console_guess: file is /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:43 console_guess returned: map:macosx:/dev/null@0x0x32:ff0000/ff00/ff
02/09/2021 10:31:43 raw fb is non-regular file: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:43 CGDisplayBaseAddress disabled by OpenGL.
02/09/2021 10:31:43 rawfb: macosx fb: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:43 w: 0 h: 0 b: 32 addr: 0x0 sz: 0
02/09/2021 10:31:43 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/0
02/09/2021 10:31:43 rfbNewFramebuffer(0x2af31eb0, 0x0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 4)
02/09/2021 10:31:43 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:43 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:43 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:43
02/09/2021 10:31:43 Raw fb at addr 0x0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
02/09/2021 10:31:43
02/09/2021 10:31:43 calling setTranslateFunction()...
02/09/2021 10:31:43 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:43 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:43 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:43 no translation needed
02/09/2021 10:31:43 done.
02/09/2021 10:31:43 Sending rfbEncodingNewFBSize for resize to (0x0)
02/09/2021 10:31:45 macosxCG_refresh_callback: register
02/09/2021 10:31:45 macosxCG_refresh_callback: unregister
02/09/2021 10:31:45 deleted 1 tile_row polling images.
02/09/2021 10:31:45 macosxCG_init: initializing display.
02/09/2021 10:31:45 macosx_opengl_init: Using OpenGL for screen capture.
02/09/2021 10:31:45 console_guess: file is /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:45 console_guess returned: map:macosx:/dev/null@0x0x32:ff0000/ff00/ff
02/09/2021 10:31:45 raw fb is non-regular file: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:45 CGDisplayBaseAddress disabled by OpenGL.
02/09/2021 10:31:45 rawfb: macosx fb: /dev/null
02/09/2021 10:31:45 w: 0 h: 0 b: 32 addr: 0x0 sz: 0
02/09/2021 10:31:45 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/0
02/09/2021 10:31:45 rfbNewFramebuffer(0x2af31eb0, 0x0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 4)
02/09/2021 10:31:45 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:45 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:45 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:45
02/09/2021 10:31:45 Raw fb at addr 0x0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
02/09/2021 10:31:45
02/09/2021 10:31:45 calling setTranslateFunction()...
02/09/2021 10:31:45 Pixel format for client 192.168.15.149:
02/09/2021 10:31:45 32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
02/09/2021 10:31:45 true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
02/09/2021 10:31:45 no translation needed
02/09/2021 10:31:45 done.
02/09/2021 10:31:45 Sending rfbEncodingNewFBSize for resize to (0x0)
```

Comment: There's too much extraneous data. Mac only supports OpenGL 2.1 in its most basic form, so whatever you're trying to do needs to be aware of that.

Comment: Hello Tetsujin, I've just checked the OpenGL version, it is OpenGL version string: 2.1 Metal - 71.7.1.
I've never changed it, it's in std form.